# Updating azure append blob storage with Postman

Tags: azure, postman, azure-blob-storage

Im trying to use postman to append azure blob storage but keep having issues with the Authorization Header and Date Header

I have taken the following steps:
Created an azure Container named : **test**
Created an appentType blob file in the above container named : **testBlob.xlsx**

I have created a Shared Access Token via:

Dashboard -> testAccountName/Containers -> test -> Shared Access Tokens :

[image]

Then I have used the Blob SAS Token in Postman as so:

[image]

I get the following 403 error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Feel as though I'm missing something obvious but cant find any answers online and so I'm asking here.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you passing the SAS token in the authorization header?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, so ive copied the Blob SAS Token I generated and added it to the Authorization header. Formatted as so:
SharedKey testAccontName:?<My SAS Token>

Comment: SharedKey testAccontName:<My SAS Token>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS token should be a part of your request URL and not the authorization header because the authorization information is already included in the SAS token.

So your request URL would be something like `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob?comp=appendblock&<sas-token>`.

You also need not include any request headers when using SAS URL as the information is already included in the SAS URL.

Please try with these changes.

Comment: I have just noticed that while I am appending my excel file, the file cant be read or opened in excel when downloaded and contains unreadable text. However when appending a .txt file it works as expected. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Excel is a binary file. Appending data to that file will corrupt its format.

Comment: Do you know how to append to a new line each time when appending a .txt file?